# How to find an algorithm better than brute force for this matrix computation?

Tags: algorithms

I have a matrix of size NxM.
Each coefficient can have either some fixed value or a joker denoted by *

- Let's take two random rows. We are going to loop through the columns. For each column, either we color it green or in red.
- We color using red when the two values in the same column have an intersection, i.e. either having the same value or one has a value and the other is a joker.
- We color using green when the two values are different and there is no jocker present in the column.

[image]

**Definition 1**: Two rows are said to be "**Friends**" if there exists at least one column that is green.

**Definition 2**: A matrix is said to be "**Acceptable**" if every two rows are friends. Otherwise, it's said to be **"Refused"**.

**Problem:** I want to determine whether a matrix is Acceptable or not.

**Attempt of solution:**

Step 1. Pick the first line, and compare it with the second (by looping on columns). If they are not friends, stop, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, continue.

Step 2. Now move on to compare the first line and the third line. If they are not friends, stop, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, continue.

...

Step n-1. Compare the first line with the nth line. If they are not friends, stop, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, continue.

Step n. Pick the second line, and compare it with the third line. If they are not friends, stop, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, continue. (We don't re-compare line 2 to line 1, it's already done in Step 1.)

Step n+1. Pick the second line, and compare it with the fourth line. If they are not friends, stop, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, continue.

...

Final Step. Pick the (n-1) the line and compare it with the last line. If they are not friendly, the matrix is refused. Otherwise, it's accepted.

**Discussion:** The complexity of the solution seems to be

M * [(N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) ...+ 1]. Indeed, for each 2-rows comparison, we are comparing M columns. On the other hand the total number of 2-rows comparisons to be done is [(N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) ...+ 1] (we compare the first line with the n-1 remaining lines, then the second line with n-2 lines, etc.)

**Is there a way to do better than this? My solution seems like a brute force.**

Thanks.

Comment: Does a histogram of value occurrences help? What if you operate *by column* instead of *by row* (pair of rows)?

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean by a histogram of value occurrences? and how to do with the jocker value * ?

Comment: [Histogram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram): For a range partitioned into bins, establish a count of events in each bin/sub-range. In programming, a bin size of 1 (count each value separately) isn't uncommon.